# Multicast Chating, to get sender's login/pc name in host/listener's GUI

Tags: java, network-programming, multicast, inetaddress, multicastsocket

Help me guys, i was able to get the IP addres of sender in host/listener system, how to get sender's name, i think it should be "packet.getHostName(string ip-address)", where packet is reference of the packet received by the listener from sender. I was able to get sender's IP by "packet.getAddress()".

below is the code:

```
al=new ArrayList();

al1=new ArrayList();

try{

            InetAddress nn = InetAddress.getByName("ALL-SYSTEMS.MCAST.NET");
            int pn = Integer.parseInt( "4000" );
            MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(pn);

            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[128], 128);
            socket.joinGroup(nn); 
            System.out.println( "waiting for a packet from "+nn+"...");
            socket.receive(packet);

            GUI.setTextArea(new String(packet.getData()));

            if(!al.contains(packet.getAddress()))
                    {
                al.add(packet.getAddress());
                al1.add(packet.getAllByName(new String(packet.getAddress)));
                    }
                    else if("EXIT".equals(new String(packet.getData())))
                    {
                al.remove(packet.getAddress());
                al1.remove(packet.getAllByName(new String(packet.getAddress)));
                    }               

            GUI.clearLoginArea();

            //for(int j=0;j<al1.size();j++){
                for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){

                    GUI.setLoginArea(al.get(i)+"");
                }
            //  GUI.setLoginArea(al1.get(j)+"");
                    //}
            socket.leaveGroup(nn);
            socket.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {

System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Socket's don't have a name.  They have an IP address.  If you want client's to have a name, you should build it into your network protocol.

Comment: Hey william, i got it resolved, thanks, you are right sockets dont have name, they have IP
I wanted name of the sender in my textare in from of the message sent by the sender. which i resolved by adding String of sender name in packet being sent by sender.

Comment: String sendPckt=senderName+": "+chatTextField.getText();

Comment: You should use some industry standard in your protocol.  I suggest XML, JSON if you're set on a string based protocol. Use Protobuf otherwise.